# Load custom jQuery and CSS into a browser for any website

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

Hi I am just wondering how I can load custom JS and CSS onto a website within the browser.

I don't have any FTP access to a website however I'd like to make some front end changes to it using local JS and CSS files and load them into the browser to make changes and show a client the front-end changes.

I am just wondering what browser might offer these features and how it can be done?

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/ https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You could use the developer tools of Google Chrome to manipulate the webpage. Or the developer tools from any browser really. If you would like to permanently change the appearance and behaviour of a webpage you could use Greasemonkey, a very popular Add-on for Firefox. A version for Google Chrome was made too: Tampermonkey.